# I can not list @onetomany nor @manytoone bidirectional

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, one-to-many, many-to-one

**Task.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_task")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idTask")
    private long idTask;
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "task")
    private List<TaskAction> actions;
    ...

public Task() {}

public Task(String taskname, String description, Date date,
        Category category, Priority priority, User user) {
    this.taskname = taskname;
    this.description = description;
    this.date = new Date((date.getTime() / 1000) * 1000);
    this.deadline = null;// new Date((deadline.getTime()/1000)*1000);
    this.category = category;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.user = user;
    this.userResponsible = null;
}

public Task(String taskname, String description, Date date, Date deadline,
        Category category, Priority priority, State state, User user,
        User userResponsible, String evaluation, int pending) {
    this.taskname = taskname;
    this.description = description;
    this.date = new Date((date.getTime() / 1000) * 1000);// delete milis
    this.deadline = new Date((deadline.getTime() / 1000) * 1000);
    this.category = category;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.state = state;
    this.user = user;
    this.userResponsible = userResponsible;
    this.evaluation = evaluation;
    this.pending = pending;
}
```

**TaskAction.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_taskaction")
public class TaskAction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idTaskAction")
    private long idTaskAction;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idTask", nullable = false)
    private Task task;
    ...

public TaskAction() {
}

public TaskAction(Task task, Date date, String action, String description,
        User user) {
    this.task = task;
    this.date = new Date((date.getTime() / 1000) * 1000);
    this.actionname = action;
    this.description = description;
    this.user = user;
}
```

**Test.java**

```
@Test
public void testTaskActionCreate() {
    taskPriorityDao.saveOrUpdate(priority);
    taskCategoryDao.saveOrUpdate(category);
    taskStateDao.saveOrUpdate(state);
    userDao.saveOrUpdate(user);

    Date rightnow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    Task t1 = new Task("My first task", "This is a task", rightnow,
            rightnow, category, priority, state, user, user, "okey", 0);

    taskDao.merge(t1);//save
    t1 = taskDao.get("My first task");

    logger.info("id Task >" + t1.getIdTask());

    TaskAction ta1 = new TaskAction(t1, rightnow, "Task action 1",
            "Task action 1 description", user);
    TaskAction ta2 = new TaskAction(t1, rightnow, "Task action 2",
            "Task action 2 description", user);
    TaskAction ta3 = new TaskAction(t1, rightnow, "Task action 3",
            "Task action 3 description", user);
    TaskAction ta4 = new TaskAction(t1, rightnow, "Task action 4",
            "Task action 4 description", user);

    taskActionDao.saveOrUpdate(ta1);
    taskActionDao.saveOrUpdate(ta2);
    taskActionDao.saveOrUpdate(ta3);
    taskActionDao.saveOrUpdate(ta4);

    System.out.println(" 1 >" + new TaskActionService().getAllTaskActions().size());
    System.out.println(" 2 >" + t1.getActions().size());
```

I'm getting these messages despite that the rows are inserted in the database.

1 > NullPointerException

2 > empty list, size = 0

**Data model**

[image]

Comment: The name `Action` is used to represent `Action Class in struts`, its a wrong practice to follow this type of naming practice in Entity class. Do correct in the future..

Answer (score 0):

You are missing adding `TaskAction` to `Task`'s `TaskAction` list `actions`

```
task.getActions().add(TaskAction)
```

For JPA to work perfectly in bi-directional mappings it is required to set the relations correctly on both sides.

In pure English - `TaskAction` knows about `Task` but `Task` is unaware of `TaskAction`

Comment: I added task constructors, but the mappings are in Task and TaskAction properties

Comment: Could you post your `TaskAction` constructor? i.e. - `new TaskAction(t1, rightnow, "Task action 1", "Task action 1 description", user);`

Comment: Added TaskAction constructors

Comment: @Joe I have modified my answer, let me know if it helps

Comment: I understand,that I must add that in @Test function, task.getActions().add(TaskAction) , am I wrong?

Comment: @Joe, Yes you can add it there, Not sure on the best practice but I would add it to the `TaskAction` constructor. Also don't forget to initialize the `actions` list. I would do that in `Task`'s Constructor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55760/discussion-between-a-agarwal-and-joe).

Comment: It work when I do this saving every taskAction independently, but not when I added them in a list in task object and then save the task.